# libGDX: Textfield with BitmapFont(true) renders the text outside the borders

Tags: java, libgdx, textfield

I'm experimenting with TextField and having problems with it when flipping the font. My orthographic camera is set to yDown = true. With that settings, the text is flipped so I came up with a solution to set BitmapFont's flip constructor parameter to true. But then when I try the code below. The text "Hello World" is rendering outside it's ninepatch borders. Here's a [screenshot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ezekielbaniaga/8314264994/) of it:

[image: screenshot]

```
    TextFieldStyle tfs = new TextFieldStyle();
    NinePatch np = new NinePatch(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(ResourceConstants.IMAGE_NINEPATCH)), 8, 8, 8, 8);

    tfs.font = new BitmapFont(true);
    tfs.fontColor = Color.BLACK;
    tfs.background = np;

    TextField tf = new TextField("Hello World", tfs);
    tf.x = 50;
    tf.y = 90;
    tf.width = 100;
    tf.height = 32;
    addActor(tf);
    tf.pack();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the method where draw is being called on tfs (which is where the coordinates are set). The cartesian y coordinates for font are opposite other GDX objects, I think because typesetting needs to work a certain way.

So if you call

```
myFont.draw(spriteBatch, "Hello World", 0, 0);
```

Then you would expect the message to be drawn right in the bottom left hand side. But this is wrong! The fonts themselves are drawn from **the top left**, so your message will be drawn on the bottom left corner of the screen, below the bottom edge. ***We wont even be able to see the message.***

But if we change the coordinates:

```
myfont.draw(spriteBatch, "box2d x: " + String.format("%2.2f", x), 10, 20);
```

We will see the message because we've given it enough room in the negative y direction to be displayed.

Given that the misbehaving font is misbehaving in the Y direction, and rendering **below** where you expect it to, I suspect that the above misconception is indeed the problem.

If you're not controlling any of the drawing coordinates of the bitmapfont itself, and this is solely handled by the TextField class, and the font is always out of bounds, no matter the size of your text field, then I would suspect a bug in GDX. You might try asking the forums about that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same effect. If you add `TextField`, and after, for example, add `CheckBox` and for this widget set setScale, then you will see this effect

```
TextField textfield = new TextField("Text field",skin);
stage.addActor(textfield);

CheckBoxStyle checkBoxStyle = skin.get(CheckBoxStyle.class);
checkBoxStyle.font.getData().setScale(2f);

CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox("CheckBox", checkBoxStyle);
stage.addActor(checkbox);
```